# Accessing Custom Permission Through Javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-permission

In my dev org, I could do `if('{!$Permission.Manage_Advanced_Org_Settings}'){}`, however, I tried to package and install in another org and got 'Manage_Advanced_Org_Setting does not exist. Check Spelling' error. I tried adding the namespace to it as well, but got the same error.

I am accessing it through JavaScript, not in an VF apex components, which may be the issue. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript and not VF?

Comment: Did you add you try `$Permission.Manage_Advanced_Org_Settings__c`?

Comment: I think you need to include the namespace. Maybe `$Permission.ns__MySetting`.

Comment: Ugh, Salesforce.... so after trying to figure out what on Earth was wrong with this, because I did have the namespace in it... Finally found out it was another piece of code that had the $Permission.Manage_Advancedblah blah without the namespace. Even though it was commented out, Salesforce was trying to read it and throwing a fit because it couldn't recognize the field with the namespace.

Comment: Seems worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that adding the namespace did indeed fix the issue. so $Permission.ns__MySetting (or whatever ones namespace and custom setting name is) is correct, while $Permission.MySetting caused the error when installed into other orgs that use a namespace.

My issue was, that a commented out $Permission.MySetting was still trying to be interpreted by SalesForce despite being commented out. And, since it didn't have a namespace, it caused the error.

I had this issue with remote method calls from my javascript to my apex controller as well. It seems any accessor of apex/salesforce that starts with '{!$' will be counted even if commented out and throw errors if any exist, which seems like a potential bug on their part that SalesForce doesn't seem to interpret comments correctly when those are in there and apparently doesn't count them as being commented out.